# tcl regexp from variable and special characters

Tags: regex, tcl

I am a bit confused 
my input string is " foo/1"
my motivation is to set foo as a variable and regexp it :

```
set line " foo/1"
set a foo
regexp "\s$a" $line does not work
```

also I noticed that only if I use curly and giving the exact string braces it works

```
regexp {\sfoo} $line works
regexp "\sfoo" $line doesnt work
```

can somebody explain why?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quick answer:**

`"\\s"` == `{\s}`

**Long answer:**

In Tcl, if you type a string using `""` for enclosing it, everything inside will be evaluated first and then used as a string. This means that `\s` is evaluated (interpreted) as an escape character, instead of two characters.

If you want to type `\` character inside `""` string you have to escape it as well: `\\`. In your case you would have to type `"\\sfoo"`.

In case of `{}` enclosed strings, they are always quoted, no need for repeated backslash.

Using `""` is good if you want to use variables or inline commands in the string, for example:

```
puts "The value $var and the command result: [someCommand $arg]"
```

The above will evaluate `$var` and `[someCommand $arg]` and put them into the string.

If you'd have used braces, for example:

```
puts {The value $var and the command result: [someCommand $arg]}
```

The string will not be evaluated. It will contain all the `$` and `[` characters, just like you typed them.

Comment: Good answer. It's possible to go into a lot more depth (e.g., strategies for doing backslash-safe substitution into REs as literals) but let's hold off on doing that unless warranted.